# calling setFrame multiple times?

Tags: ios, performance, uiview, frame, cgrect

i am calling setFrames multiple times for the same view.

for example after setting ltr views frames, i check if the layout should be rtl and change the views frames again.

```
-(void)setViewsFrames:(BOOL)RTL{
      view1.frame = CGRECMAKE();
      view2.frame = CGRECMAKE();
      view3.frame = CGRECMAKE();
         .
         .
         .
      if(RTL){
         [view1 setRtlFrame];
         [view2 setRtlFrame];
         [view3 setRtlFrame];
            .
            .
            .


      }

}


-(void)setRtlFrame{
    CGRect RTLFrame = self.frame;
    RTLFrame.origin.x = [self superview].frame.size.width - self.frame.origin.x - self.frame.size.width;
    [self setFrame:RTLFrame];
}
```

does calling setFrames multiple time force the system to draw the view multiple times ? and may that effect performance.

I am using that also in UICollectionViewCell, so the system calls `setViewsFrames:` every time she want to draw the cell.

**EDIT:**
i've did a small test. i check when drawRect is called and here is the result:

- it's called just one time, no matter how much times setFrame was called.
- in UICollectionCellView it called just when the cell created or at reload.

Comment: Add a breakpoint in `drawRect` and check yourself.

Comment: @dasdom thank you for your reply,but How to add a breakpoint to drawRect, i can't open UIVIew.m file.

Comment: You can create your one view and use that. Just to verify what is going on. Then you can switch back to use `UIView` instances.

Comment: @dasdom thanks, i will do it.

Comment: @dasdom drawRect is called just one time, no matter how much times setFrame was called. also in UICollectionCellView drawRect called just one time even when you scroll the cells, so draw rect called just when the  cell is created. very strange yes ?

Comment: basically the system updates the UI after the loop cycle ends, does not matter how many times you have updated the `frame` in the cycle, the actual update will happen when cycle ends; however you can force the update immediate after every changes, calling the `-layoutIfNeeded` which causes the system won't wait until the cycle ends but does the update immediately – bear in mind if you don't want to change the actual size of the view but its location only, updating the `center` property is far more efficient procedure than updating the entire `frame`.

Comment: @holex thank you, but what the definition of cycle ?

Comment: @david, khm... the cycle ends, when you finished the job on the main thread or if you'd like that way: when your last invoked method reaches the end of its scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting the frame calls 'setNeedsLayout' and then on the next runloop iteration, IOS knows to layout & redraw the view.

there'd be no point in layouting / redrawing stuff the user doesn't see so iOS coalesces the calls for you -- if you let it by using the setNeedsXY methods

### so the overhead of setting the frame is normally minimal

(except if you deal with custom (badly implemented) views [which you don't ;)])

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what is the setNeedsXY methods? what do you mean with badly implemented views ? why drawRect is not called on scrolling uicollectionViewcell , as on scrolling ios need to draw the cell again , right ? thanks again

Comment: 1. setNeedsXY is setNeedsDisplay and setNeedsLayout - but the concept can be transferred to other use cases in theory

Comment: 2. badly implemented: views that call [self layoutSubviews] or [self display] instead of using the setNeedsXY methods to delay/coalesce these operations

Comment: 3. the view's layer is cached and as long as its bounds don't change it doesn't have to be redrawn. if you need it to be call setNeedsDisplay but redrawing just because of scrolling?! that would kill scrolling performance

Comment: BOUNDS.. independant of origin

Comment: i change the frame of a view in my cell, and the redraw wasn't called although the size and origin was changed.(on the screen i could see that the view has changed), how this happens ?thanks

Comment: also i note that uilabel drawRect called every time the cell scrolled !! why ? thanks

Comment: I don't know the internal of the classes.. maybe the cell doesn't call setNeedsDisplay and maybe labels redraw based on some other mechanism. I don't know

Comment: it's ok thanks, the most important thing that calling setFrame multiple times won't effect performance.